# Enable windows auth for Kestrel on NET5 asp.net core webapp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, .net-5, kestrel-http-server

I've created test app in Visual Studio 2019 from template ASP.NET Core Web App (Target framework: .NET 5.0 (Current).

And now I want to set up this app for using windows auth as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel

- I've installed nuget package
- I've added `services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();` in Startup.ConfigureServices
- I've added `app.UseAuthentication();` before `UseAuthorization` as described in [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

And I correct also index.cshtml to indicate logged username:

```html
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome, @HttpContext.User.Identity?.Name</h1>
```

But when I publish this site to folder (Target Runtime: Portable) and copy to remote windows server (server in domain, of course. It's Windows Server 2012) with NET5 installed - I see no username when browse website. (I run WebApplication2.exe from command line)

What's wrong in my case or what should I check to fix this problem?

PS My Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddNegotiate();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

This works on my own workstation, which is also a part of same domain. It's shows my username even without installing this nuget package (in IIS mode).

I've checked also not only chrome, but IE and Firefox - same result.

And I've checked that protocol is not HTTP/2:

[image]

---

When I added this string to my appsettings.json:

```
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Debug"
```

then I can see this message in console log:

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler[9]
      AuthenticationScheme: Negotiate was not authenticated.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an [working example](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Security/Authentication/Negotiate) in [aspnetcore sources on github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore). And it works on my server also.

So, after comparing two solutions line by line I've found the difference.

In additional to what official documentation told you need to add this line in Startup.cs:

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
        });
```

You need specify DefaultPolicy, because it contains `.RequireAuthenticatedUser()` call:

```
public AuthorizationPolicy DefaultPolicy { get; set; } = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(Array.Empty<string>()).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
```

If you add only `services.AddAuthorization();` this won't work.